# condition in Eval while Binding data in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, conditional-statements

This is my Code in Asp Gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commented By">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <h3 class="sfUserName">
<%#Eval("UserName")%></h3>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here i have to check

```
if (<%#Eval("UserName")%>=="Annons")
{
   //Bind <%#Eval("Name")%>
}
else if (<%#Eval("UserName")%>!="Annons")
{
   //Bind <%#Eval("UserName")%>
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
<h3 class="sfUserName">
    <%# Eval("UserName").ToString() == "Annons" ? Eval("Name") : Eval("UserName") %>
</h3>
```

Comment: @BijayaKhadka, why didn't you pointed this answer as the correct answer? This helps people that are facing the same issue to find a solution and also improves your aprovement rate:)